# What is the benefits of organizing programming code?

Tags: xcode

Why do we need to organize code? What are the objectives of organizing code. Organizing code is a time consuming process until it becomes habit. I am trying estimate the cost and benefits of organizing any programming code

Comment: why asking this question here? theres plenty example on google, be specific please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine you are at the library; none of the books at the library are organized. If your work depends on finding references in books, you will waste a lot of time searching for the books. This may be a quick process if you have only a few hundred books, but when you have thousands or tens of thousands of books, you will need to ensure the books stay organized in order to efficiently locate them. You could also say "Organizing books is a time consuming process", but the end result is that it saves you time when/if they are kept organized.

The same thing happens as software becomes more complex. People won't want to add programs which are not well organized to well organized programs/codebases. It's hard to use/maintain programs which are complex and organized poorly (or not at all).

One of the biggest problems if you are faced with organizing a codebase is that it's very monotonous and time consuming -- it's easy to (unknowingly) introduce changes which result in bugs; these changes should receive significant testing (but it's not likely that a disorganized codebase has high test coverage). Disorganized programs which are reused and/or have long lifetimes usually require significantly more maintenance time over the life of the program.

If you're just banging out a proof of concept that is 100 lines and will remain independent of all other programs, you don't have to obsess over the organization of that program.

Answer (score 0):

Organized code becomes much easier to maintain and extend over time than code that is placed wildly about. That's why programmers take so much care to name variables/methods/etc. well, keep methods short and specific, and so on. I would recommend reading [Clean Code by Robert Martin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882).